# Register dependency of class library which is not directly referenced in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, class-library

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project with class libraries. I can register dependency of class library which are directly added as references into the project. But I am not able to find way to register dependency of class library which are not directly added to the project.

For example, as you can see in following screenshot:

[image]

1. It is the ASP.NET Core Web API project.
2. It has a class library `FirstClasslib` project.
3. The `FirstClasslib` project is added as reference to the ASP.NET Core Web API project.
4. `FirstClasslib` project has dll reference of `SecondClasslib` project.
5. `SecondClasslib` is also a library with interface and its implementation as shown in the following screenshot:

   [image]

I want to register dependencies of `SecondClasslib` through DI like I did for `FirstClasslib`. But since it is not directly linked to the ASP.NET Core Web API project, how can I do this?

Please find source code repo at https://github.com/sujadkar/WebApplication1

I tried `BuildServiceProvider` approach but many people are saying it is anti pattern and we should avoid. I want to resolve dependency of `SecondClasslib` using Dependency Injection.

Edit 1 -
Instead of using the Extension method and calling method from the Startup.cs class Can we use the following approach?

In secondclasslib could we add the following

```
public class SecondFactory
{
    public static ISecondClass CreateProvider() {
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(ISecondClass),typeof(SecondClassImplementation));
        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        ISecondClass secondClass = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISecondClass>();
        return secondClass;
    }
}
```

In firstclasslib we can get instances using the following code,

```
public class FirstClassImplementation : IFirstClass
{
    public void SubmitRequest(int hello)
    {
        ISecondClass secondClass = SecondFactory.CreateProvider();
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me if this is the correct approach for dependency registration and getting instances?

Comment: I am curious why people think this is an anti-pattern myself. Normally you'd just import the library and set it up via the builder. If you wanted to build a classlib for just your imports you could do that too and then use that to DI all the classes you wanted into your app as well but I dont think that's really necessary here.

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-applications-entry.

Comment: But long story short: as library dependencies are transitive, your ASP.NET Core project already references `SecondClassLib` implicitly. As the dependency already exists, there is no reason *not* to add the reference directly between the two libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your API project to add a reference to `SecondClassLib`, then in your `FirstClassLib` project, create an extension method like this:

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSecondClassLibServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // register all services here
        services.AddScoped<ISecondClass, SecondClassImplementation>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

Then in your Web API project, use:

```
builder.Services.AddSecondClassLibServices();
```

For multiple projects, you need a compose root project to register all services as above and your main project to refer to this project

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this solution and it is working. I have one more thought instead of adding an extension method could we register dependency directly from the second lib service? Please refer to the Edit 1 section of the question. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't try as you've shown,when we try with dependency injection,we don't care how the instance of dependency was created,the DI system would solve it for us,what you need to do is just register the services in the same container(IServiceCollection)  and inject the services/class when it is required as dependency

Comment: here are some documents/articles related :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#dependency-inversion

Comment: https://medium.com/@cfryerdev/dependency-injection-composition-root-418a1bb19130